# Python Selenium test does not run when using absolute path to Firefox geckodriver

Tags: python, linux, selenium, python-unittest, geckodriver

I am trying to run Selenium test in Python on Linux Ubuntu environment.
Geckodriver is located in my project root folder.
I run the file named siteTest.py from PyCharm command line:

> python3 siteTest.py

However, I do not see any output from Selenium.
The test worked before I divided it into setUp, test and tearDown and added *self* as a parameter.
Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

```
import os
import unittest
 
from selenium import webdriver
 
 
class siteTest:
    def setUp(self):
        ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.curdir)
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=ROOT_DIR + '/geckodriver')
 
    def test(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get('https://google.com/')
 
    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program was near perfect. You just need to annotate the `siteTest` *class* as `unittest.TestCase`. So effectively, you need to rewrite the line:

```
class siteTest:
```

as:

```
class siteTest(unittest.TestCase):
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to annotate your set up and tear down methods.

```
@classmethod
 def setUp(self)
  .
  .

@classmethod
 def tearDown(self)
  .
  .
```

Here, I have annotated as class method so it will run only once for the class.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to use you suggestion, but still no effect. I'll experiment later.