# Python Selenium: Unable to Locate Element on Amazon

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've been trying to fill the input:

```
<input id="turbo-checkout-pyo-button" data-testid="" class="a-button-input" type="submit" value="Place your order" aria-labelledby="turbo-checkout-place-order-button-announce">
```

I've tried:

```
placeorderBtn = order = browser.find_element_by_id("turbo-checkout-pyo-button")
```

I always get:

> Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="turbo-checkout-pyo-button"]"}

It doesn't seem to work. I don't know if I am giving enough info, so if you need more info of this to help me, please, let me know!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Try to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using **=** two times?
Just use:

```
placeorderBtn = browser.find_element_by_id("turbo-checkout-pyo-button")
```

Also, wait for this button to become clickable.
Message says you are using css selector.
Use it correctly. # is added for ID elements.
In your case it will be:

```
placeorderBtn = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#turbo-checkout-pyo-button")
placeorderBtn.click()
```

**Try 2:**
Based on comments:
Try this xpath:

```
locator = "//input[text() = 'Place your order']"
```

or,

```
locator = "//span[text() = 'Place your order']"
```

**Try 3:**

To click use

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                (By.XPATH, "//span[text() = 'Place your order']")))
locator = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text() = 'Place your order']')
locator.click()
```

**Try 4:**

Use the locator:

```
placeorderBtn = browser.find_element_by_id("turbo-checkout-place-order-button-announce") 
placeorderBtn.click()
```

Comment: Still gives me the:
Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#turbo-checkout-pyo-button"}

Comment: Is page completely loaded?

Comment: for debugging add time.sleep(10), where 10 is number of seconds to wait. It can be less. If it works, add explicit wait (check my other answers hot to do it)

Comment: I played around with the code you gave me (thank you for it), but instead of the error I got a while ago, I am now receiving the "no such frame: element is not a frame"
Here is my code:
browser.maximize_window()
            import time
            time.sleep(10)
            browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_class_name("a-button-input"))
            browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Place your order']").click()
            buyButton = True
            print("Item was purchased.")

Side note: I am very new to this, so I apologise in advance.

Comment: Mistake is here: browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_class_name("a-button-input")) This element is not iframe. It's input. It would be nice if you could share more html code related to the page you are working with.

Comment: If you want, I can attach more of the html code, but it will have to be later (not home currently, so in about 9 hours from now lol), but if you want the entire html of what I am working with, it is on Amazon, the “Place Your Order Screen”. More specifically, not the sending you to a new link, but the on screen option that comes up when you click “Buy Now” on some items. I have tested it with different products, and certain items have different “Buy Now” screens, only 2, but if you get the one that is just another layer instead of another link, you can inspect element the “Place Order” button.

Comment: Also, if what I typed was too confusing, which I think it was, I’ll attach more code later if needed.

Comment: Ok, please attach it.

Comment: I'll check it tomorrow

Comment: Sounds good. Thank you for taking time to do so :).

Comment: Here is also what my code looks like now. I am trying to fix the stuff that is under the "except:" title.
https://ibb.co/bNdDTb1
(The "try:" code is working perfectly fine.)

Comment: Ok, thanks for update. I did not have free time to check it today.

Comment: Oh, it's fine. No rush! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you busy this weekend, or would you be able to help me?

Comment: HI, I think you do not need except here. Why do you use it?

Comment: Do you have a link to the site?

Comment: So, I am creating 2 different ways of purchasing on Amazon, because it is so inconsistent. So, for a few items, as shown here: https://ibb.co/kBqR351, it takes you to a different link where you place your order, whereas here: https://ibb.co/KqqrmXC, it is just another layer on top of an existing link. I need to make it so that it covers both the whole new link and the layer on a link when purchasing. That is why I am using it, but I cannot figure out why it is saying "Element is not in Frame". The link is random items on Amazon, if you want to try it out for yourself.

Comment: I'm trying to click the "Place your order" button on this link: https://ibb.co/KqqrmXC

Comment: Any idea @vitaliis?

Comment: I added one more possible xpath. If it won't work, than the problem is different, not locator.

Comment: Ok. I actually tried it, and it seemed to work. The last step of that was clicking the "Place your order" button. Since it is an xpath, is it still possible to click? Thanks in advance, @vitaliis!

Comment: Please also paste more html code to your question. Use any html formatter online so the could would look good.

Comment: Yes it is possible, of course. Don't forget to accept/upvite. And check official selenium tutorial on how to set up selenium. It is not difficult.  Here is the example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63640783/python-selenium-test-does-not-run-when-using-absolute-path-to-firefox-geckodrive

Comment: The html looks a bit wonky when I put it in a formatter, so here's a picture of it... sorry!
https://imgur.com/a/TAkde8h
The highlighted box is the button
Thanks again, @vitaliis.

Comment: Also, I cannot upvote because I do not have enough reputation, lol, but I will most definitely accept your answer after looking at the link! Thank you again!

Comment: Thank you for all of the solutions, but, for #4, I got an error saying that I could not click on it since it is not clickable. For #3, which I will be focusing on, I am getting a random error with no message...
https://imgur.com/a/pz8klQF
@vitaliis

Comment: Nevermind! I got it figured out! Thank you soo much for your time and help! It really means a lot to me. Although I am new to this, I have spent hours on this, and you majorly helped me out! Thank you again for your help!