# trouble installing selenium on pycharm

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have created a project on Pycharm, added the selenium to folder to my new project called 'selenium' and added the chromedriver to the folder.

I use this to test it:
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.chrome()
browser.get('http://seleniumhq.org/')

it doesnt work and shows me this:
/Users/andres/PycharmProjects/selenium/selenium/bin/python /Users/andres/PycharmProjects/selenium/TEST.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/andres/PycharmProjects/selenium/TEST.py", line 3, in 
browser = webdriver.chrome()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1

what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

First:
Add the code that you are executing.
Second:
Do you import selenium into your project?

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

Check similar questions before asking, like this
[TypeError: 'module' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534438/typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Well... I went to preferences, Python interpreteter, add, selenium. Then added the chromedriver to the selenium, bin folder. Is that correct? For importing selenium into the project?

Comment: Check here, it's similar. You also should add the path you chromedriver https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63640783/python-selenium-test-does-not-run-when-using-absolute-path-to-firefox-geckodrive

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please apvote/accept.